# Select elements whose numeric data attribute is in a given range in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have multiple html elements with a numeric data attribute:

```
<div data-content="1"></div>
<div data-content="2"></div>
<div data-content="3"></div>
<div data-content="4"></div>
<div data-content="5"></div>
<div data-content="6"></div>
```

How can I select only some of these whose data attribute is between two numbers let's say 2 and 6. So I don't have to manually list them in CSS like this:

```
div[data-content="2"], div[data-content="3"], div[data-content="4"], div[data-content="5"], div[data-content="6"] {
  display: none;
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
div[data-content="2-6"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Is there a shorthand syntax for this? Regex or something?

Comment: No, css is not a programming language. you can use SASS for those kind of things.

Comment: are your elements always ordered?

Comment: What demands that you want to select 2-6? Will that change upon user interaction or any kind of data that is being loaded into the site?

Answer (score 0):

Css is not consider by many as a programming Programming Language.
This is not possible.

You can use SASS/SCC a CSS pre-processor.

```
//SASS
@for $i from 2 through 6
      div[data-content="#{$i})"]
```

Comment: No idea why your answer got downvoted... Now that I know that I can't do it in CSS, you just gave me an alternative solution in CSS preprocessors, which is fine

Comment: @TemaniAfif you just did answer you own question, CSS selectors are selectors/filters.
You start at the top and go down, filter and filter more, but you cannot go up.

Comment: I didn't ask any question ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif For the lulz, if you state that you do not see the relation implicit you asked yourself that question xD

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot achieve the effect you desire.

As an alternative, you can use JavaScript to select the elements and apply the desired styles.

This can be achieved by storing the `data-content` values in an array and using JavaScript to generate a selector (with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)) which you can use to select the elements (with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) and loop through (with [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)):

```js
const valuesToHide = ['1', '3', '6'];

const selector = valuesToHide.map(e => `div[data-content="${e}"]`).join(',');

console.log(selector)

document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(e => e.style.display = "none")
```

```html
<div data-content="1">1</div>
<div data-content="2">2</div>
<div data-content="3">3</div>
<div data-content="4">4</div>
<div data-content="5">5</div>
<div data-content="6">6</div>
```

Comment: I did miss the JavaScript tag...
Select elements whose numeric data attribute is in a given range in **CSS**

Comment: I did answer the question and gave a alternative solution, you did not even answer the question :P

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs I did. I provided an alternative solution using an alternative language.

Comment: but still did not answer the question.

Comment: congratulations. well done, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can style a range of elements based on their order, but not on their data attributes:

```css
div:nth-of-type(-n+6) {
  display: none;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a form that has an event listener on the button. The form takes a minimum value and a max and will hide all divs containing numbers outside the range.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let lowerBound = parseInt(document.getElementById("lbound").value);
  let upperBound = parseInt(document.getElementById("ubound").value);
  let myElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
 
  for (const element in myElements) {
    if ((myElements[element].dataset.content >= lowerBound) && (myElements[element].dataset.content <= upperBound)) {
      myElements[element].style.display = "block";
    } else {
    myElements[element].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div data-content="1">1</div>
<div data-content="2">2</div>
<div data-content="3">3</div>
<div data-content="4">4</div>
<div data-content="5">5</div>
<div data-content="6">6</div>


  <label for="lbound">Lower Bound:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="lbound" name="lbound"><br>
  <label for="ubound">Upper Bound:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="ubound" name="ubound"><br>
  <button onclick="myFunction()"> 
    Highlight Values
</button>
```